# Invoking method without using the name of the method

Tags: c#

I recently saw some code like this (which is calling a delegate):

```
public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Second watch: Method '{0}' on object '{1}' was invoked  and caught in order {2}.", input.MethodBase.Name, input.Target.GetType(),Order));
    return getNext()(input, getNext);

}
```

Can someone explain and \ or post a link explaining what is happening here. I understand Invoke() is being called but why is the name optional in this case?

Answer (score 2):

GetNextHandler appears to be a delegate which returns a delegate.

Thus calling it yields a delegate which is then called with two parameters.

```
 public delegate void FooDelegate( int n );
 public delegate FooDelegate GetFooDelegate();

 public void Bar( GetFooDelegate getFoo ) {

      getFoo()( 5 );

 }
```

Comment: Why would you have to? Delegates can be invoked with ()

Comment: That's what I am asking. Do you have a link to the MSDN documentation explaining this?

Comment: That rather basic stuff but here you are http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx in section "calling a delegate".

Comment: I understand how delegates work. I don't see the answer to my question in that documentation however plus that is old stuff. I don't see it in the 4.0 docs either. I'm looking for where it is actually documented.

Comment: @MikeCheel You ask for MSDN documentation listing this, it's provided, and then you say it's not good enough?  Clearly, this is how it works.  You'll see this being done almost anywhere you see delegates being used.  MSDN documentation was provided.  If that's not sufficient then I'd say you have unreasonable expectations.

Comment: I understand how it is working but I don't see where it talks about omitting the word 'Invoke' which is what is happening here. I didn't see that in your old link. I also don't see mention of it in the new documentation. Why would wanting to see this behavior described be unreasonable?

Comment: "A delegate object is called by using the name of the delegate object, followed by the parenthesized arguments" - from the link above. Why you insist to have Invoke there?